# New line characters showing in program card description

Tags: java, arraylist, newline, bufferedreader, readline

I am using Java to create a Tarot Card Reader for a class project. It reads information from a text file. What's strange is that when I run the program the newline operators print out instead of actually creating a new line.

Here is the code:

```
public class TarotDAO {
    public static ArrayList < TarotCard > getAll() {
        ArrayList < TarotCard > cardList = new ArrayList < > ();

        //Create something to read from the file
        Path thePath = Paths.get("cars.txt");
        File theFile = thePath.toFile();
        try (
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(theFile))
        ) {
            //read each line of the file
            String curLine = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(curLine);

            while (curLine != null) {
                String[] temp = curLine.split(">");

                //---create a new object with the values from the array
                //add object to results
                String id = temp[0];
                String name = temp[1];
                String upright = temp[2];
                String reverse = temp[3];
                TarotCard card = new TarotCard(id, name, upright, reverse);
                cardList.add(card);

                //...or as a 1-liner
                //results.add(new ExpenseReport(temp[0], Double.parseDouble(temp[1])));

                //get the next line from the file
                curLine = reader.readLine();
            }
            return cardList;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        return cardList;
    }
```

}

```
package Business;

public class TarotCard 
{
    protected String name;
    protected String identifier;
    protected String upright;
    protected String reverse;

    public TarotCard (String identifier, String name, String upright, String reverse)
    {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.name = name;
        this.upright = upright;
        this.reverse = reverse;
    }

    public TarotCard()
    {

    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() 
    {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) 
    {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String getUpright() 
    {
        return upright;
    }

    public void setUpright(String upright) 
    {
        this.upright = upright;
    }

    public String getReverse() 
    {
        return reverse;
    }

    public void setReverse(String reverse) 
    {
        this.reverse = reverse;
    }

    public String getImage()
    {
        String image = identifier + ".jpg";
        return image;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "";
        result += this.getName() + "\n\n";
        result += this.getUpright() + "\n\n";
        result += this.getReverse();
        return result;
    }
}
```

This the code that prints everything out:

```
    package Application;

    import Business.TarotCard;
    import Controller.TarotDAO;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE;

    public class Reading extends javax.swing.JDialog 
    {

    public Reading(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) 
    {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the 
    form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        cbSpread = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        lblGenLove1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblGenLove2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblGenLove3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblGenLove4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lbl3Card3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lbl3Card1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lbl3Card2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        chkInclRev = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        btnSave = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnDeal = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnShuffle = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cbDeck = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        taResult = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        lblBackground = new javax.swing.JLabel();


    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Reader");
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1143, 835));
        setModal(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1130, 800));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        cbSpread.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(136, 54, 25));
        cbSpread.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Felix Titling", 0, 12)); // 
        NOI18N
        cbSpread.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 204));
        cbSpread.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] 
    { "Select Spread", "3 Card", "General Love Reading" }));
        getContentPane().add(cbSpread);
        cbSpread.setBounds(820, 20, 190, 30);

        lblGenLove1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                lblGenLove1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(lblGenLove1);
        lblGenLove1.setBounds(20, 70, 240, 400);

        lblGenLove2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                lblGenLove2MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(lblGenLove2);
        lblGenLove2.setBounds(300, 120, 240, 400);

        lblGenLove3.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                lblGenLove3MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(lblGenLove3);
        lblGenLove3.setBounds(570, 120, 240, 400);

        lblGenLove4.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                lblGenLove4MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(lblGenLove4);
        lblGenLove4.setBounds(850, 80, 240, 400);

        lbl3Card3.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                lbl3Card3MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(lbl3Card3);
        lbl3Card3.setBounds(840, 100, 240, 400);

        lbl3Card1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                lbl3Card1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(lbl3Card1);
        lbl3Card1.setBounds(50, 100, 240, 400);

        lbl3Card2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                lbl3Card2MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(lbl3Card2);
        lbl3Card2.setBounds(450, 100, 240, 400);

        chkInclRev.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(117, 47, 24));
        chkInclRev.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Felix Titling", 0, 12)); // 
        NOI18N
        chkInclRev.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 204));
        chkInclRev.setText("Include Reversals?");
        getContentPane().add(chkInclRev);
        chkInclRev.setBounds(580, 20, 160, 30);

        btnSave.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(117, 47, 24));
        btnSave.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Felix Titling", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        btnSave.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 51));
        btnSave.setText("Save");
        getContentPane().add(btnSave);
        btnSave.setBounds(1030, 20, 80, 31);

        btnDeal.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(117, 47, 24));
        btnDeal.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Felix Titling", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        btnDeal.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 51));
        btnDeal.setText("Deal Cards");
        btnDeal.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnDealActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnDeal);
        btnDeal.setBounds(410, 20, 150, 31);

        btnShuffle.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(117, 47, 24));
        btnShuffle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Felix Titling", 0, 12)); // 
        NOI18N
        btnShuffle.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 51));
        btnShuffle.setText("Shuffle Deck");
        btnShuffle.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnShuffleActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnShuffle);
        btnShuffle.setBounds(240, 20, 150, 31);

        cbDeck.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(136, 54, 25));
        cbDeck.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Felix Titling", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        cbDeck.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 204));
        cbDeck.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { 
    "Select Deck", "Rider-Waite" }));
        cbDeck.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cbDeckActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(cbDeck);
        cbDeck.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 30);

        taResult.setEditable(false);
        taResult.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 51));
        taResult.setColumns(20);
        taResult.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Footlight MT Light", 0, 18)); // 
        NOI18N
        taResult.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 204));
        taResult.setLineWrap(true);
        taResult.setRows(5);
        taResult.setAutoscrolls(false);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(taResult);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2);
        jScrollPane2.setBounds(10, 550, 1110, 240);

        lblBackground.setIcon(new 


   javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/Background/Magick- 
     Background2.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(lblBackground);
        lblBackground.setBounds(0, 0, 1132, 800);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void cbDeckActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        String deckSelect = (String) cbDeck.getSelectedItem();

    }                                      

    private void btnShuffleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        if (cbDeck.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select Deck"))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Select a deck before shuffling.", "WARNING", WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
            if (cbDeck.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Rider-Waite"))
            {
                cardList = TarotDAO.getAll();
                Collections.shuffle(cardList);
            }
        }
    }                                          

    private void btnDealActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        if (cbDeck.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select Deck"))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Select a deck before dealing.", "WARNING", WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if (cbSpread.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select Spread"))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Select a spread before dealing.", "WARNING", WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
            if (cbDeck.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Rider-Waite"))
            {
                if (cbSpread.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("3 Card"))
                {   
                    lblGenLove1.setVisible(false);
                    lblGenLove1.setVisible(false);
                    lblGenLove1.setVisible(false);
                    lblGenLove1.setVisible(false);
                    lbl3Card1.setVisible(true);
                    lbl3Card2.setVisible(true);
                    lbl3Card3.setVisible(true);
                    card1 = cardList.get(0);
                    card2 = cardList.get(1);
                    card3 = cardList.get(2);
                    lbl3Card1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/Back.jpg")));
                    lbl3Card2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/Back.jpg")));
                    lbl3Card3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/Back.jpg")));
                }
                else if (cbSpread.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("General Love Reading"))
                {
                    lbl3Card1.setVisible(false);
                    lbl3Card2.setVisible(false);
                    lbl3Card3.setVisible(false);
                    lblGenLove1.setVisible(true);
                    lblGenLove1.setVisible(true);
                    lblGenLove1.setVisible(true);
                    lblGenLove1.setVisible(true);
                    card1 = cardList.get(0);
                    card2 = cardList.get(1);
                    card3 = cardList.get(2);
                    card4 = cardList.get(3);
                    lblGenLove1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/Back.jpg")));
                    lblGenLove2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/Back.jpg")));
                    lblGenLove3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/Back.jpg")));
                    lblGenLove4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/Back.jpg")));
                }
            }
        }
    }                                       

    private void lbl3Card1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        if (cbSpread.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("3 Card"))
        {
            String cardImage1 = card1.getImage();
            lbl3Card1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/" + cardImage1)));
            taResult.setText("This card is about your past:\n\n" + card1.getUpright());
        }
    }                                      

    private void lbl3Card2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        if (cbSpread.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("3 Card"))
        {
            String cardImage2 = card2.getImage();
            lbl3Card2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/" + cardImage2)));
            taResult.setText("This card is about your present:\n\n" + card2.getUpright());
        }
    }                                      

    private void lbl3Card3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        if (cbSpread.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("3 Card"))
        {
            String cardImage3 = card3.getImage();
            lbl3Card3.setIcon(new 
    javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/" + 
    cardImage3)));
            taResult.setText("This card is about your future:\n\n" + card3.getUpright());
        }
    }                                      

    private void lblGenLove4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        if (cbSpread.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("General Love Reading"))
        {
            String cardImage4 = card4.getImage();
            lblGenLove4.setIcon(new 
    javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/" + 
    cardImage4)));
            taResult.setText("This card is general glimpse of your future:\n\n" + card4.getUpright());
        }
    }                                        

    private void lblGenLove3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        if (cbSpread.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("General Love Reading"))
        {
            String cardImage3 = card3.getImage();
            lblGenLove3.setIcon(new 
    javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/" + cardImage3)));
            taResult.setText("This card tells you how to prepare yourself:\n\n" + card3.getUpright());
        }
    }                                        

    private void lblGenLove2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        if (cbSpread.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("General Love Reading"))
        {
            String cardImage2 = card2.getImage();
            lblGenLove2.setIcon(new 
    javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/" + cardImage2)));
            taResult.setText("This card advises of a positive omen to look for:\n\n" + card2.getUpright());
        }
    }                                        

    private void lblGenLove1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        if (cbSpread.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("General Love Reading"))
        {
            String cardImage1 = card1.getImage();
            lblGenLove1.setIcon(new 
     javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Business/RWImages/" + cardImage1)));
            taResult.setText("This card is general glimpse of your future:\n\n" + card1.getUpright());
        }
    }                                        
    ArrayList <TarotCard> cardList;
    TarotCard card1;
    TarotCard card2;
    TarotCard card3;
    TarotCard card4;
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnDeal;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSave;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnShuffle;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cbDeck;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cbSpread;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox chkInclRev;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl3Card1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl3Card2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl3Card3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblBackground;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblGenLove1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblGenLove2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblGenLove3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblGenLove4;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea taResult;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here is an example of what the output is:

```
Upright Nine of Swords Meaning\n\nThe Nine of Swords is often associated with fear and anxiety, 
about all the things that worry you and keep you up at night. Sometimes this card can be associated 
with trauma - one which may be shameful for you to confide with others about, and all the 
psychological responses that come from experiencing that trauma.\n\nWhen we are never released from 
the entrapment depicted in the Eight of Swords, we escalate into the Nine of Swords, where we are 
plagued by nightmares.
```

Here is what some of the text file I'm calling in looks like:

> 0MA>The Fool>Upright Fool Meaning\n\nThe Fool card is numbered 0, which is 
>       considered to be a number of infinite potential. Consider him a blank slate, 
>       for The Fool has yet to develop a clear personality. He is the symbol of i 
>       innocence - his journey to come will shape his character yet.\n\nTo see the 
>       The Fool generally means a beginning of a new journey, one where you will be 
>       filled with optimism and freedom from the usual constraints in life. When we 
>       meet him, he approaches each day as an adventure, in an almost childish way. 
>       He believes that anything can happen in life and there are many 
>       opportunities that are lying out there, in the world, waiting to be explored 
>       and developed. He leads a simple life, having no worries, and does not seem 
>       troubled by the fact that he cannot tell what he will encounter ahead.\n\nTo 
>       meet him in a reading can also be seen as a call to the risk-taking part of 
>       your own character. He inspires courage, for he understands that every day
>       is a chance to open up new areas in your life, and with that comes a mixture 
>       of anticipation, wonder, awe and curiosity. The Fool is there to show 
>       that...

I've also tried a CRLF, that hasn't worked either. I've tried making it so the program would read two delimiters, that unfortunately did not work either. I am new to Java and am still learning so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. From your code I can only see one statement printing the first line. Are you sure you're not just seeing the first line of the file printed?

Comment: Maybe you want to change '\' character and 'n' character to '\n' character?

Comment: Show us your input file. Escaped characters work in Strings, but you should think of them as quoted Strings, not just collections of characters. If you have a text file that has \n, then you're also going to print \n rather than a newline.

Comment: @openingnow I did write it out as '\n'...they aren't separate characters

Comment: @MarsAtomic I added in a snippet of the input file, it couldn't been far to long to put up the whole text file. That is interesting. So since its coming from a text file the \n actually gets printed out instead of a newline....is there are work around then? Is there a way to print the new line?

Comment: @camp When you read \n from file, it is not '\n' character. It is just '\' and 'n'.

Comment: I guess thats pretty much what @MarsAtomic was saying. Since that doesn't create a newline within the program is there a way to alter the code so I can get those newlines?

Answer (score 1):

Your output contains \n because your input literally contains \n. That character combo you're seeing is not a newline, but literally a slash followed by an n, so it's not shocking that if it's in your input, you'll see it in your output.

Escaping characters only works with String literals, i.e. when you create a String object like this:

```
String foo = "I need a newline on the end of this line.\n";
```

If you `print(foo)`, you'll get the text, followed by a newline, as specified.

If you read a file containing \n, that's not a newline. Newlines are non-printing characters.

Solution: at the end of each line in your input, press your return key instead of typing \n.

Another solution: if you insist on retaining the \n character combo in your input file, you'd need to process the line to get rid of them before using the input.

```
curLine = curLine.replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

Note that I have escaped the backslash because we're using a regular expression here, otherwise, the regex would be looking for newlines, not \n.

If you want to use a newline only in your output, just print it using `System.out.println();` or append a newline to the end using `+ "\n"`. You didn't include the part where you're printing stuff, so I have no idea what you're actually doing.

Comment: I added the part where the program prints stuff out. I apologize that I didnt before. I tried adding the    'curLine = curLine.replaceAll("\\n", "");' but I am still getting the same problem. Do I need to add more into my println() sections to stop printing the \n? I also tried just replacing the \n with hitting return in the text file and for whatever reason the program crashed

Comment: @camp So you changed your input file, correct? It seems you've edited it to remove the \n\n character sequence, but *did you press the enter key* after each line? Your input is a wall of text now. How will your program know where newlines are if you don't actually use any? Type a line. Press the [ENTER] key. The cursor moves to a new line. Type the next line. That's how your input file should be constructed.

Comment: I did try pressing the enter key in place of each \n in the text file and the system ended up crashing.

Comment: @camp Umm... yeah, pretty sure that's not what happened. When you say "crash," what actually happened? Did the program stop with an exception? Did the program just freeze? Did it just close? You're going to have to be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: The program froze, nothing printed out and I had to do a hard close

Comment: @camp You're going to have to learn how to use the debugger and find out where your program is getting stuck (which should also tell you why). Your program probably is not crashing at all, but rather, endlessly processing something. Set breakpoints on every line of your program, run the debugger and wait for the problem to show up.

Comment: @camp You have three classes you're working with, right? TarotDAO, Reading and TarotCard? You've posted all but the TarotCard class itself. Post that and I'll have all the pieces to run the code on my end, which I can do when I get the chance.

Comment: just added the tarotCard class